# Solving a separable differential equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

Solve the differential equation:

$$y'=\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}$$

My book says the solution is: $$y=\frac{x+c}{cx+1},$$ where $c$ is a constant.
It's been ten minutes I tried to verify if it was correct but I'm pretty sure the book is wrong. Can someone confirm it?

Comment: Ten minutes is not much. Try harder.

Comment: The integral of the differential equation is:

$\frac{1+y}{1-y}=\frac{1+x}{1-x}c$
I think it's correct...
So how to find the explicit equation: $$y=\frac{x+c}{cx+1}$$

Comment: Solve $\frac{1+y}{1-y}=A$.

Comment: $y=\frac{A-1}{A+1}$

Comment: Now you have it. What's $A$ ?

Comment: Ohh yes I've read...too simple XD

Comment: @user155542.. the answer is right. Look at my solution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust is right. [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_Last_Theorem) took 358 _years_ ;)

Answer (score 10):

We have
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}.
$$
Using separation variable we obtain
$$
\frac{dy}{1-y^2}=\frac{dx}{1-x^2}.
$$
Integrating both sides yields
$$\eqalign
{
\int\frac{dy}{1-y^2}&=\int\frac{dx}{1-x^2}\\
\frac12\int\left[\frac{1}{1+y}+\frac{1}{1-y}\right]\ dy&=\frac12\int\left[\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right]\ dx\\
\ln(1+y)-\ln(1-y)&=\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)+C_1\\
\ln\frac{1+y}{1-y}&=\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}+C_1\\
\frac{1+y}{1-y}&=C_2\cdot\frac{1+x}{1-x}\\
y&=\frac{k_1x+k_2}{k_2x+k_1}\quad\Rightarrow\quad\text{dividing by}\ k_1\\
\color{blue}{y(x)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{x+c}{c\, x+1}}.
}
$$
where $C_2=e^{C_1}$, $k_1=C_2+1$, $k_2=C_2-1$, and $c=\dfrac{k_2}{k_1}$.

Comment: answer is not wrong @tunk-fey. It is just well arranged

Comment: @Dmoreno Thanks for your editing.

Comment: You are welcome @Tunk-Fey!

Comment: _"Using separation variable we obtain"_: I've been calling that "cross-multiplying" my entire life. Is it not called that when working with derivatives?

Comment: @Cole No, because [$dy/dx$ is not a fraction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-fracdydx-not-a-ratio/21209#21209).  Of course, the effect is the same because of the chain rule.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I usually use that term when dealing with differential equation.

Answer (score 7):

$$y'=\frac{cx+1-c(x+c)}{(cx+1)^2}=\frac{1-c^2}{(cx+1)^2},$$
$$\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}=\frac{\frac{(cx+1)^2-(x+c)^2}{(cx+1)^2}}{(1-x^2)}=\frac{(c^2-1)x^2+(1-c^2)}{(cx+1)^2(1-x^2)}=\frac{1-c^2}{(cx+1)^2}.$$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
\text{Separate:} && \frac{dy}{1-y^2} & =\frac{dx}{1-x^2} \\
\text{Partial fractions:} && \frac{1}{2}\left(\int\frac{1}{1+y}dy+\int\frac{1}{1-y}dy\right) & =\frac{1}{2}\left(\int\frac{1}{1+x}dx+\int\frac{1}{1-x}dx\right) \\
\text{Integrate:} && \log\frac{1+y}{1-y} & = \log c+\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) \\
\text{Solve for $y$:} && y & =\frac{c+cx-1+x}{c+cx+1-x} \\
\text{Factor:} && y & =\frac{x(c+1)+c-1}{x(c-1)+c+1} \\
\text{Divide by $c+1$:} && y & =\frac{x+\frac{c-1}{c+1}}{\frac{c-1}{c+1}x+1} \\
\text{Let $k=\frac{c-1}{c+1}$:} && y & =\frac{x+k}{kx+1}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

The book is correct. If you will show how you calculated that it isn't, I can show you where you made a mistake. Show us how you calculated $y'$ and how you calculated $\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

By integration from a table of primitives, $argth(y)=argth(x)+c$, so that
$$y=\tanh(argth(x)+c).$$
(Can be shown to be the same as the given solution.)